# (R, purrr) iteration over pairs of columns by name, one constant & one from a list

Tags: r, iteration, parameter-passing, purrr, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to produce a list of graphical objects (grobs), suitable for passing to gridExtra::grid.arrange (or some ggequivalent if that is easier). I have redrafted my example to eliminate multiple problems that were kindly pointed out by @MrFlick and @Ronak Shah. However, I still get the same error message:

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : unused argument (NULL)
```

(and I don't get a single google hit for "`unused argument (NULL)`" `r` | `purrr`. The closest I find is `unused argument (.null = NA)`.)

Each object is a set of four plots (plotted together) that are output as side effects from the `acf` or `pacf` functions, showing the autocorelation and autocovarience between two variables and their various lags. I am trying to write a function that will take a tsibble, a vector of independent variable column names from that tsibble, and the name of a single outcome variable (also a column in the input tsibble) and, using purrr, take the `acf` or `pacf` of the pairs of variables defined by the single name with each of the specified columns, convert the plot to a grob, and output a list of the grobs.

Here is my non-working function, acf version:

```
acf_grobs <- function(dat., mod_nms, outcome){
  depend <-  select(dat., all_of(mod_nms))
  out <- map(depend, ~ grob(acf(x=cbind(.x, y))), y = dat.[[outcome]])
  out
}
```

And a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)
```

I know that this loads a lot more packages than needed for this example, but I am loading all these packages for other reasons.

```
aa  <- 1:4
bb  <- 1:4
cc  <- 1:4
day <- 1:4
tb  <- tibble(aa, bb, cc, day)
tsb <- as_tsibble(tb, index = day)

var_of_interest <- "aa"
mod.nms <- c("bb", "cc")

pacf_grobs(dat. = tsb, mod_nms = mod.nms, outcome = var_of_interest)
```

I still believe the error message is caused by my failure to pass the single argument `outcome` to the function argument of purrr::map correctly, though this belief is shaken because I am now passing it a different way, and still getting the same error message.

Comment: `tsb <- tsibble(aa, bb, cc, day, index = day)` This line returns an error `Error: Column names \`<int>\`, \`<int>\`, and \`<int>\` must not be duplicated.`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `.data[[outcome]]`? There is no `.data` defined anywhere (though it is defined by `dplyr` -- is that how you are trying to use it? Because `.data[["anything"]]` will return NULL there. And then you seem to be passing that to `map()` to a function that only expects one parameter. That's where the unused argument is coming from. For example `map(1:3, function(.) .+2, 4:6)`

Comment: I'm sorry, @Ronak Shah. I accidentally omitted a line. I have no idea why creating a tibble and then converting it with as_tsibble works while doing directly, i.e. tsibble(aa, bb, cc, day, index = day), does not, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick ! I am always amazed by people who can figure out what I am confused about, when I myself am not merely confused, but also confused about what I am confused about. You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Here is what I was trying to do: data[[outcome]] is intended to refer to a column in the data set depend. Somewhere( in the map vignette, I think) it says that what you are iterating over goes before the function, while constant parameters come after. What I want the .data[[*]] function to do is to act as a pronoun, evaluate outcome to its content string, treat the string as a name, & refer back to to the data: depend assigned positionally  The select step is superfluous here, but needed to subset my real data.

Comment: The function does a redundant acf of outcome = aa with itself, because I did not know a reliable way to get map's post-function parameter to refer back to .dat, here tsb. If I did, I would drop aa from depend and just have it be outcome.

Comment: I figured that the parameter could not find .dat because of map's nonstandard evaluation.

Comment: You haven't really changed the line which was causing error `tsb <- tsibble(aa, bb, cc, day, index = day)` is still there and gives the same error. You are calling `pacf_grobs` function whereas what you have defined is `acf_grobs`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Ronak Shah  It works if you do tibble (without index = day) first, followed by as_tsibble with index = day second.   For me at least.

Comment: you are right about the acf/pacf mixup. I have two of these functions, one with each. I fixed it above to be consistent.